# Show remaining seconds or countdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

someone help me with my code to show (Please wait countdown or waiting seconds remaining.
the code is working, but i just want to show reaming seconds

like show reaming time when the button will be enabled again from disabled

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <button id="votebutton">Submit</button>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
</form>
<script>
function submitPoll(){
    document.getElementById("votebutton").disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("votebutton").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'Please wait ' + countdownNum + '';
    }, 5000);
    
}

document.getElementById("votebutton").addEventListener("click", submitPoll);
</script>
```

Comment: yes i want to show reaming seconds the button to be enabled again on id countdown <div id="countdown"></div>

Comment: What is `countdownNum` ?

Comment: It seems you need `setInterval` with 1000 miliseconds interval instead of a `setTimeout` with 5000 miliseconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple working snippet.

```js
function submitPoll(){
  let btn=document.getElementById("votebutton"), 
      cdn=document.getElementById("countdown"),
      n=5;
  cdn.innerHTML = 'Please wait ' + (n--) + ' seconds.';
  btn.disabled = true;
  let t=setInterval(function() {
    if (n) 
      cdn.innerHTML = 'Please wait ' + (n--) + ' seconds.';
    else {
      cdn.innerHTML='';
      btn.disabled=false;
      clearInterval(t);
    }
}, 1000);

}

document.getElementById("votebutton").addEventListener("click", submitPoll);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <button id="votebutton">Submit</button>
  <div id="countdown"></div>
</form>
```